# Flex: Move a datapoint from 1 location to another in a plotchart

Tags: charts, flex3

I have a flex plotchart and I need an animation that would enable me to move datapoints from 1 location to another. The actual movement must also be shown.

I have tried move control but the call to play() does not work.

Any hints would also help greatly..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort, I found that one way to move the point from 1 point to another is by making it move along the equation of the line and rendering the intermediate points on the graph after some delay...

I'll share the code...

Place the following line where you want to start the movement:

```
        setTimeout(showLabel,singleDuration,oldLocation,newLocation, 
                Constants.TOTAL_STEPS,1,oldLocation.x, oldLocation.y, singleDuration);
```

And this is the function definition:

```
        private function showLabel(oldLoc:Object newLoc: Object, totalSteps: Number,
                        count:Number, currentX: Number, currentY: Number, singleDuration: Number): void{
            tempArrColl = new ArrayCollection();
            var tempObj: Object= new Object();
            xDelta = 0.25;
            yDelta = 0.25;
            tempObj.x = currentX + (xDelta * count);
            tempObj.y = currentY + (yDelta * count);
            if ((tempObj.x >= newLoc.x) || (tempObj.y >= newLoc.y)){
                tempObj.x = newLoc.x;
                tempObj.y = newLoc.y;
                callLater(showPoint,[tempObj]);
                tempArrColl = new ArrayCollection();
                plotGraphArrayColl.addItem(newLoc);
                return;
            }
            callLater(showPoint,[tempObj]);
            count++;
            setTimeout(showLabel, singleDuration, oldLoc, newLoc, 
                totalSteps, count, tempObj.x, tempObj.y, singleDuration);
        }

        private function showPoint(loc: Object): void {
            tempArrColl.addItem(loc);
            plotChart.validateNow();
        }
```

Here, tempArrColl will hold the intermediate point along the line equation. Put it as a dataProvider in a series on the graph and then once all the points are moved, remove it. plotGraphArrayColl is the dataProvider that would hold the newly moved points..

There may be better ways possible but it worked for me... Do tell if anyone finds something easier.. Thanks